# how to check if a webpart already exists on a page or not

Tags: 2007, web-part, development, site-collection, web-part-page

I am adding three webparts with different titles to a given page url, but I need to check if webpart is already on page or not, here is the code i am using atm to add webpart to the page.

```
     using (SPSite mySite = new SPSite(PageUrl))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = mySite.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                            using (SPLimitedWebPartManager manager = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager("default.aspx", PersonalizationScope.Shared))
                            {
                            webpart webpart = new webpart();
                            webpart.AllowClose = true;
                            webpart.AllowMinimize = true;
                            webpart.AllowConnect = true;
                            webpart.ChromeType = PartChromeType.None;
                            webpart.ChromeState = PartChromeState.Normal;
                            webpart.AllowZoneChange = true;
                            webpart.AllowHide = true;
                            webpart.ExportMode = WebPartExportMode.All;
                            webpart.Hidden = false;
                            webpart.AllowEdit = true;
                            webpart.AllowZoneChange = true;
                            webpart.AllowHide = true;
                            webpart.ButtonCSSClass = "DefaultButton";

                            manager.AddWebPart(webpart, "Right", index);
                            }
                      }
                 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is LINQ code that finds a Web Part with a title:

```
    string _webPartTitle = "mywebpart";
    //Retrive the webpart with some title
    IList<Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart> _listFormWebParts = (from _wp in manager.WebParts.Cast<Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart>()
                                                                            where string.Compare( _wp.Title , _webPartTitle  , true ) == 0
                                                                            select _wp).ToList();

    //Check if there are any web parts found
    if (_listFormWebParts != null)
    {

    }
```

Comment: getting error on  'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPLimitedWebPartCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and no extension method 'Cast' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPLimitedWebPartCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Add a reference ´using System.Linq;´

Comment: sorry forgot to mention, I am using .net 2.0 :/

Comment: Can i use "SPLimitedWebPartManager" to get webparts of a page and then match there title or webpart object..

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/02fbf849-864c-4803-80ae-f8c438af9796

is what i was looking for :)

Comment: I left out something to figure out yourself :-)